# Как получить полный путь к файлам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система, path

Есть папка, вида:

```
C:\path\
   folder
   folder
   file
```

Используя метод `os.listdir(path)` получаю список всего, что в ней есть.

Как я могу получать полный путь к каждому файлу в папке и во вложенных папках вне зависимости от уровня вложенности?

Как я понимаю тут нужно создать некую рекурсивную функцию, но как это сделать не очень понимаю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r"C:\download\aaa")
files = [str(f.absolute()) for f in path.glob("**/*")]
```

---

результат:

```
In [8]: files
Out[8]:
['C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\titanic',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\2020-05-13_19h57_41.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\2020-05-13_20h00_51.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\2020-05-25_11h11_54.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\2020-06-09_14h01_53.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\2020-06-10_15h33_42.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\2020-06-10_16h19_57.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\2020-06-10_16h27_42.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\2020-06-10_16h32_45.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\Thumbnails',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\Thumbnails\\2020-05-13_19h57_41.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\Thumbnails\\2020-05-13_20h00_51.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\Thumbnails\\2020-05-25_11h11_54.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\Thumbnails\\2020-06-09_14h01_53.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\Thumbnails\\2020-06-10_15h33_42.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\Thumbnails\\2020-06-10_16h19_57.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\Thumbnails\\2020-06-10_16h27_42.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\ScreenShots\\Thumbnails\\2020-06-10_16h32_45.jpg',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\titanic\\.ipynb_checkpoints',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\titanic\\preprocess.ipynb',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\titanic\\preprocess.py',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\titanic\\sol.py',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\titanic\\test.csv',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\titanic\\titanic.7z',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\titanic\\train.csv',
 'C:\\download\\aaa\\titanic\\.ipynb_checkpoints\\preprocess-checkpoint.ipynb']
```

---

Если в результирующем списке нужны только файлы (без директорий), то можно сделать так:

```
files = [str(f.absolute()) for f in path.glob("**/*") if f.is_file()]
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, второй раз за день выручаете